# Align container divs

Tags: html, css

I have this on my page. i wanted the container divs to align at the center. so i gave display:inline-block. but it didn't work. why is this happening? is there a way to display the containers as inline-block elements so that they appear exactly at the center?

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="definition">
            <p>Nothing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="container">
        <div id="definition">
            <p>Nothing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="container">
        <div id="definition">
            <p>Nothing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
   vertical-align:top;
}
#image {
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#definition {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align:top` to the `inline-block` element.. if that doesn't work, add your CSS.

Comment: it didn't work.:-( i have added the css.

Comment: In your css I am not seeing any `inline-block` and I believe JoshC was saying to add that as well as keeping the `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: yes, i did with the inline-block. but it didnt work either.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or something so we can see what is happening?

Comment: It's worth noting that an element is no longer `inline-block` if you are using absolute positioning..

Comment: i wanted image and deinition to align at the top of each other.

Comment: here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Juw5C/

Comment: The easiest way of centring elements vertically is by using `display:table` and `display: table-cell`. However, I really can't see what exactly you are trying to achieve here. I get that you want to centre the divs, but how do you want them to be aligned relative to each other? Also, what is the significance of setting everything to `position:absolute`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` this code will centre the divs on the page: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Juw5C/1/). Hopefully this is the effect you want.